# How to cancel a subscription (not StreamSubscription) in flutter in_app_purchase?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I am trying to create a menu option that cancels a customer subscription, but I cannot find a method that does that.
For example, if a customer buy a monthly subscription product in play developer console and then he/she does not what to be subscribed anymore, then he will be able to cancel this subscription.
Is there any solution for this scenario?

Comment: They can cancel such subscription on the Playstore or Appstore

Comment: Hi JideGuru, Thank you for the response. Yes, I see that in the playstore/appstore then can cancel. But, I was wondering if this is possible through the flutter api.

Comment: Did you solve this???

Answer (score 0):

Image taken from: [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/.)
[image: https://www.revenuecat.com/]

They provide flutter
sdk for managing subscription related functionality.

As a workaround you can launch url that redirects to `Manage Subscription` page and user can manually opt-out of renewal.

you can use url_launcher plugin to redirect to AppStore/Playstore as answered here: [Flutter - Redirect user to the Subscription page in PlayStore/AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298230/flutter-redirect-user-to-the-subscription-page-in-playstore-appstore)