# Flutter - Redirect user to the Subscription page in PlayStore/AppStore

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I read that "Currently, the In-app Billing API does not provide support for programmatically canceling subscriptions from inside the purchasing app", I would like to redirect the user to this page to manage his own subscription.

I am using the following package [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) to implement the In-app Module.

I'm not able to find how to open the subscription page from an application in Flutter.

Answer (score 14):

You can launch the following URL. which will redirect to the `Manage Subscription` page in App Store for Apple.

```
launchUrl(Uri.parse("https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions"));
```

and u can launch the following URL for Android.

```
launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions?sku=pro.monthly.testsku&package=com.example.app'));
```

with replacing the `sku` and `package` for Android.

You will need to add [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) in `pubspec.yaml`

and import this package too,

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

Comment: Just to add some clarification. On Android, if you don't set the SKU, it forwards the user to the regular subscriptions screen on Google Play.

Comment: Update: on Android, passing SKU to the URL seems to have no effect. It just forwards the user to the regular manage subscriptions screen.

Comment: I'm using `launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);` to open the Google Play app.

Comment: It's been suggested [in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78128383/5211833) that the Android URL changed to `https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions`. [Source](https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions).